# Clustering with Tensorflow 2

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0, k-means

I have a dataset of 1600 points in the 3D dimension. I need to use a clustering algorithm (like K-means) to cluster them into for example 10 different clusters. I want to use the Euclidean distance to do this clustering. How can I do this in TensorFlow 2?

Comment: Most basic clustering algorithms like K-means don't require gradient computation or backpropagation. The only benefit of using Tensorflow over Numpy I see here is GPU acceleration. If that is the case, you can simply replace numpy ops with corresponding TF ops.

Comment: You may also want to look at GPU accelerated Numpy variants like https://cupy.dev

Comment: You can use `tf.compat.v1.estimator.experimental.KMeans` , for more details on the library you can find here https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/estimator/experimental/KMeans